# Writing an octal string as ASCII characters using echo command

Tags: java, linux, shell, exec, sh

I am trying to create a shell script from java code. I am using following method to create the shell script.

```
 String cmd = "echo -e \"echo -e abc\\\0177\\\0177\\\0177\\\0177\\\0177\\\0177\\\0177\\\0177\" > ";

    String [] commands = { "/system/bin/sh", "-c", cmd + "script.sh " }; 
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commands);
```

However, when I open the script.sh file I see following :

```
echo -e abc\*7\*7\*7\*7\*7\*7\*7\*7
```

What I want is the following:

```
echo -e "abc\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177\0177"
```

What is wrong with I am doing ? Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting `*` characters there? I get something else (characters that are not really visible). Then again, I don't have a "/system/bin" so I used "/bin/bash". What shell is `/system/bin/sh`? What operating system is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need this but you can use single quote in `echo` and 2 backslashes:

```
String cmd = 
 "echo -e 'echo -e abc\\\\0177\\\\0177\\\\0177\\\\0177\\\\0177\\\\0177\\\\0177\\\\0177' > ";
```